# How can I remove data type information from my xml in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, hash

I converted ruby hash data to xml.
My xml includes key type such as type="integer"

```
<problemID type="integer">3</problemID>
```

How can I remove the type information from my xml? such as the line below

```
<problemID>3</problemID>
```

Here is my code which generates xml from hash data.

```
my_xml = my_hash.to_xml(:root => 'problem')
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: What is in `my_hash`? Where does `to_xml` come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `skip_types: true`:

```
my_hash = {problemID: 3}
my_xml = my_hash.to_xml(:root => 'problem', skip_types: true)

puts my_xml
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
# <problem>
#   <problemID>3</problemID>
# </problem>
```

From the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/to_xml):

> Unless the option `:skip_types` exists and is true, an attribute “type”
>   is added as well according to the following mapping: